# Kotlin: cannot use const val from companion object in an outer enum class

Tags: kotlin, enums, static, kotlin-companion

I have a Kotlin *enum class* defined like this:

```
enum class EnumClass(val string: String) {

    VALUE_A(A), // [1]

    VALUE_B(B); // [2]

    companion object {

        const val A = "A"

        const val B = "B"
    }
}
```

and the compiler gives me following errors in lines **[1]** and **[2]**:

```
Variable 'A' must be initialized
Variable 'B' must be initialized
```

I can solve this error by extracting the consts to the top-level of source file but I don't like this solution. Is there any other way around this problem?

Comment: strange enough, if you fully qualify the `A`/`B` it works, i.e. `VALUE_A(yourpackage.EnumClass.A)` did not give me any compiler errors...

Comment: I assume this is an error in the compiler....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by fully qualifying `A` and `B`:

```
enum class EnumClass(val string: String) {
    VALUE_A(EnumClass.A), 
    VALUE_B(EnumClass.B); 

    companion object {
        const val A = "A"
        const val B = "B"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. What's strange is that after adding the qualifier Android Studio marks it as `Redundant qualifier name`...

Answer (score 1):

This will no longer be allowed in 1.9. See [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-49110) ticket.

[image]